# upload video on a Convergence Application

Tags: samsung-smart-tv

***hi everybody i try to develop a web application that can control Smart tv like this guide http://samsungdforum.com/Guide/tut00024/index.html i work fine but now i would like to upload video from computer then it can display on the smart tv like image shown on the tutorial have any one any idea or exemple or suggestion about modification of code that can i do that can help me i would like to modify code of convergence tutorial than can sens message or send video client application to smart tv application***

Answer (score 1):

Sending files is covered by the tutorial. You can find API reference for this [here](http://samsungdforum.com/Guide/ref00003/convergence_app_clienttotvappcomm.html#file-upload-methods).

Sending video file is not exactly a wise thing, because there is a 3MB limit for a file that can be sent using Convergence API. This API is designed for sending messages between TV and external client rather than files. If you want to launch video playback, send video URL from web app to the TV and let the TV download the video by itself.

Comment: have you any exemple of this i don't understand how can i send video url and let the video download by itself